# angular 2 validation on dynamic generated fields in loop

Tags: html, validation, angular, typescript

I have a list of input fields that are generated with a model. I am trying to add validation to them.
The requirement is they should not be empty or less than 2 characters.
problem is in the documentation only shows validation with non-dynamically generated variable Name. My fields are all generated dynamically. So there is no tempVariableName I can hardcode (otherwise they conflict), so I created temp variable from the name of the property I binded the field to. So I came up with something like this :

```
    <div *ngFor="let field of connector.configFields">
    <label>{{field.name}}</label>
    <input [(ngModel)]="field.value" [type]="field.name === 'Password' ? 'password' : 'text'"
           placeholder="{{field.name}} (required)"
           ngControl="[fieldName+field.name]"
           required minlength="2"
           #fieldName+[field.name]="ngModel" />
    <div *ngIf="(fieldName+[field.name]).errors && ((fieldName+[field.name]).dirty || (fieldName+[field.name]).touched)">
        <span *ngIf="(fieldName+[field.name]).errors.required">Enter Name</span>
        <span *ngIf="(fieldName+[field.name]).errors.minlength">Name minimum at 2 characters</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the configFields in typescript look like this :

```
export class FieldModel {
public name: string;
public type: string;
public value: any;
```

}

But this simply would not work. I am new to angular 2 so I am not exactly sure what I did wrong.

Comment: See this documentation: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/dynamic-form.html

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the unique `index` for each field in the array. Use this together with the `name` attribute (and `ngModel`) which will evaluate each form controls separately. So each input field gets the unique name, eg:

```html
name="f{{i}}"
```

where we get `{{i}}` from the iteration:

```html
<div *ngFor="let field of connector.configFields; let i = index">
```

So finally, your template could look like this:

```html
<form #myForm="ngForm">
  <div *ngFor="let field of connector.configFields; let i = index">
    <input name="f{{i}}" [(ngModel)]="field.value" [type]="field.name === 'Password' ? 'password' : 'text'" required #f="ngModel" minlength="2"/>
    <div *ngIf="f.errors && (f.dirty || f.touched)">
      <div *ngIf="f.errors.required"> This field is required </div>
      <div *ngIf="f.errors.minlength"> Min 2 chars </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Here's a live

### [Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/HqbR1cJLCqxn2yozrUDq?p=preview)

Comment: This is interesting. This means that angular can bind value to frontend temp variables as well as the backend code.

Comment: Not really sure what you mean? With *backend code*, do you refer to a model/values received from backend that can be set e.g as default values, or what do you mean? :)

Comment: BTW, I changed one-way binding to two-way binding of your fields, since I saw you have used it in your question, so in case you need/want it...

Comment: Glad to hear! :) Have a great day/evening/morning depending on your timezone :P and happy coding!

Comment: nice simple explanation. Got a proper answer from here.. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Prepare data in model and return to angular. Angular and hard logic in the template = bad friends.

Answer (score 0):

But if you have a select option and if has *ngFor for option then error message loses its mapping, due second *ngFor loop

better to define custom class for error message and use css display: **none** or **block*

```
.custom-valid-box{
  display: none;
 }

.form-control-danger + .custom-valid-box{
   display: block;
 }
```